# How to highlight selected and unselected text and icon of recycler view items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my main layout i have a map fragment and a RecyclerView like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/places_recycler"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView contain items with an icon(ImageView), a text(TextView) and a location detail. when an item added the icon and text show in recylcerView and it's location detail show on map. It works correctly. But i want highlighted icon of selected item and also change color of marker of this item on map and also change icon of unselected item from highlighted to normal form and it's marker to default color.
my RecyclerView item code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/places"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/places_locIc"
        />
    <CustomViews.CustomTextView
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/places_locIc"
        android:id="@+id/places_address"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:id="@+id/places_edit"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/places_edit"
        android:id="@+id/places_remove"
        android:src="@drawable/remove"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
package Adapters;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.prj.shopt.R;
import com.prj.shopt.Utility;

import java.util.List;

import Models.Place;

public class PlaceRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceRecyclerAdapter.PlaceHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    List<Place> placeList;
    public List<Marker> markers;
    public PlaceRecyclerAdapter(List<Place> places,List<Marker> markers){
        this.placeList=places;
        this.markers=markers;
    }
    @Override
    public PlaceHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.places_item,parent,false);
        return new PlaceHolder(view,markers,parent.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlaceHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(placeList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return placeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    static class PlaceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        int preMarkerPosition;
        int preImageId;
        ImageView edit,delete;
        TextView address;
        List<Marker> markers;
        public PlaceHolder(View itemView, final List<Marker> markers, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            this.markers=markers;
            edit=itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_edit);
            delete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_remove);
            address=itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_address);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(preMarkerPosition<0) {
                        preMarkerPosition = 0;
                        //preImageId=view.findViewById(R.id.places_locIc).getId();
                    }
                    markers.get(preMarkerPosition).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Utility.smallMarker(context)));
                    markers.get(getLayoutPosition()).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Utility.bigMarker(context)));
                    (view.findViewById(R.id.places_locIc))
                            .setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placehighlight));
                    //(view.findViewById(preImageId)).setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placesdefault));
                    preMarkerPosition=getLayoutPosition();
                }
            });
        }
        public void bind(Place place){
            address.setText(place.getCity());
            edit.setOnClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Post the code of `onBindViewHolder` of your `Adapter` class and also xml layout of row for `RecyclerView`. Then we could help you.

Comment: `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>` where integer would be position and boolean would be whether its highlighted. In `onBindViewHolder`, check for value and set views accordingly. When use select/clear any item, make necessary changes in hashmap and call `notifyItemChanged` for that position.

Comment: @RahulKumar for apply changes I should write it in onBindViewHolder? if i click on an item this method will call? @ jantursky i edited my question

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer yes. the logic of showing if item is selected should be onBindViewHolder. The logic of modifying hashmap should be onClickListener.

Comment: Thank you  @RahulKumar and how i understand which item is un-selected ?

Comment: well, you can have onClickListener inside of `onViewHolder` where `position` will be accessible.